# How to install cpanm dependencies?

Tags: perl, cpan

What can I do to make this working?

I'm no perl expert thus I can't give anymore details except that a tools installation manual instructs me to run this line:

```
cd ~
cpanm --sudo --installdeps .
```

Returns

```
--> Working on .
Configuring /home/user ... N/A
! Configuring . failed. See /home/user/.cpanm/work/1532680018.20391/build.log for details.
```

Log

```
cat /home/user/.cpanm/work/1532680018.20391/build.log


cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7044 on perl 5.026002 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
Work directory is /home/user/.cpanm/work/1532680018.20391
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.33
You have /usr/bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.30

You have /usr/bin/unzip
--> Working on .
Entering /home/user
Configuring /home/user
-> N/A
! Configuring . failed. See /home/user/.cpanm/work/1532680018.20391/build.log for details.
```

Answer (score 6):

The instructions you are following seem to be wrong.

You are trying to install your home directory as if it were a CPAN module… which it isn't.

The instructions probably should have said to run that command after `cd`ing to wherever you extracted the install file to.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't use the `cpanm` script use the `cpan` script instead. This handles the dependencies for you be default. You can find the correct parameters to use by doing `perldoc cpan` on the command line.

Comment: `cpanm` installs dependencies too.

Comment: `cpanm` is also used by Travis-CI, so if you want automated builds on github, you'll have to use `cpanm`.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `cpan` to install `cpanm`.

```
cpan App::cpanminus
```

This will install its dependencies automatically. Then you can use `cpanm` to install other modules.

You can use `cpanm` to update itself.

```
cpanm App::cpanminus
```

Comment: The absence of `cpanm` doesn't seem to be the problem here. That would give a completely different error message.

Comment: @DaveCross In which case, reinstalling it will update its dependencies and install any new ones.